# Update Job Descriptions in AD using Email Addresses Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, directory

I am currently attempting to write a powershell script that will update the Job Description of Various Users in Active Directory via a CSV File

The identifier I have been given to use is the User's Email Address instead of Username (Which I think would of been easier!)

Can anyone assist as I am struggling to write anything effective that works! :(

Comment: Well what have you tried?
Show us some code and we may help you. Also please take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, suppose your .csv looks like this:

```
"email","jobtitle"
"user1@mydomain.com","New job description for user1"
"user2@mydomain.com","New job description for user2"
"user3@mydomain.com","New job description for user3"
```

you could then do something like

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Import-CSV -Path <PATH-TO-YOUR-CSV-FILE> | Foreach-Object {
    # properties from the csv
    $mail  = $_.email
    $title = $_.jobtitle
    Get-ADUser -Filter {(mail -eq "$mail")} | Set-ADUser -Title $title
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't solve peoples problem when they show no effort. This just promotes bad behaviour (SO isn't a coding service).

Comment: I know, but since this is his first ever question to SO I didn't want to scare him away...

Comment: These kind of question mostly come from people asking their first question. Still we should try to keep our standard on SO. If they edit their question and actually improve their post you can reward them and give an correct answer :).

Comment: Thank you Theo, I appreciate the "push" and I certainly won't be posting any further vague questions without examples of my initial work/coding